# LLVM not compiling jump instructions correctly

Tags: llvm, riscv

I am trying to compile a c language program with LLVM(for RISC-V cross-compiling).
The jump instruction does not get compiled correctly.

For example, the the "jal" instruction will be compiled like this.

*rom.s

```
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
jal ra, main
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
<some inst.>

main:
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
<some inst.>
```

When I dump the rom.o(made from rom.s) into rom.dmp, it looks like

*rom.dmp

```
1e0:  <some inst.>
1e4:  <some inst.>
1e8:  <some inst.>
1ec:  jal ra, 0
1f0:  <some inst.>
1f4:  <some inst.>
1f8:  <some inst.>

1fc:  main:
200:  <some inst.>
204:  <some inst.>
208:  <some inst.>
20c:  <some inst.>
```

I think the compiler is failing to resolve the function name in the jump instruction.
The offset is always 0.(jumps to itself)
Is there any solution or things that I can check?

I am kind of in a hurry, so if I am lacking information
please tell me what information is needed.

Thank you

the commands I am running to compile and check is

*compile.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

clang -c --sysroot=/<path_to_tool_chain>/riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu/ \
        rom.s --target=riscv32 -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -o rom.o

llvm-objdump -d rom.o |& tee rom.dmp
```

Comment: If you're just compiling with `-c` (i.e. generating an object file, rather than an executable), it'll not resolve jump targets in other object files. This is only done during linking. Try linking with the object file containing your `main` function and running `objdump` on the resulting executable: you'll see the jump is correctly resolved.

Comment: if you're using objdump, add `-r` so you can see the relocations.

Comment: @swineone Thank you, I managed to create an executable by undefining -c option and using riscv32-unknown-linux-gnu-ld to link. The symbols were correctly resolved.